# Entries are empty when adding an IIS website

Tags: iis

Entries are empty when adding an IIS website
[image: https://ibb.co/e4g2Ye]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1: Follow these steps**

1) Remove WAS (Windows Activation Services)

2) Remove IIS

3) Reboot

4) Install WAS

5) Install IIS

6) Reboot

**2: Add new Website**

In left side base expand the tree and select Sites option. Right click on sites and select Add Website

[image]

This will open a popup to input new website details. Input the following details in the pop-up box.
Site name: Name of the website to appear in IIS listing.
Application pool: Select an application pool or keep is the default to create a new application pool same name as the site name.
Physical path: Enter the location of website pages on the system.
Binding:
Type: Select protocol to configure (eg: HTTP or https)
IP address: Select IP address from drop list to set dedicated IP for the site or keep is the default to use shared IP.
Port: Enter port on which site will be accessible for users.
Hostname: Enter the actual domain name you want to use.
Start Website immediately: keep this box checked to start site.

[image]

**3: Adding Website Alias**

If you want to add website aliases like “www.tecadmin.net”. Open IIS, Select your site and click on Bindings. You will get Site binding screen like below

[image]

Click on Add button it will open site binding box.

[image]

Enter the hostname of your site aliases like www.tecadmin.net, demo.tecadmin.net or stage.tecadmin.net and input other details and click Ok.

[image]

**4: Verify Configuration**

To verify configuration you can simply access site in a web browser. If your domain is not pointed to this server do host file entry and check.

Comment: dont open IP Window 
Bidding type null

Comment: @Z.Kirik do you want to bind your Application with specific IP ?

Comment: @Z.Kirik check out the answer again, now I add the way of binding IP

Comment: Yes I am not :(

Comment: Which IIS version do you have  ?

Comment: IIS 8.5.9600.16384

Comment: Brother, I got a fix for your problem, follow these steps

1) Remove WAS (Windows Activation Services) 2) Remove IIS 3) Reboot 4) Install WAS 5) Install IIS 6) Reboot

After that second reboot, all of my bindings were back... Yay :)

Comment: How remove Windows Activation Services

Comment: @Z.Kirik https://computerstepbystep.com/windows_activation_technologies_service.html